# Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jayant/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist

Tags: macos, homebrew, memcached

While running memcached server on mac i'm getting this
`Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jayant/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist`

I tired `brew services restart memcached` command to start the memcached server on mac but get this exception , please anyone have any idea why i am getting this error please help

Comment: You should install that missing package with brew firstly.